# error: 40 in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2

I created database in visual studio 2010 after this I install SQL management studio 2008 R2 now I open visual studio and open database but it give following error.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Did you _verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections_?

Comment: You've mentioned installing VS and and SQL Management Studio - but you don't actually mention that you've installed SQL server. Presumably it's on a different machine? Are the appropriate firewall ports open? Can you connect to it using the management studio on your local machine?

Comment: yes i installed sql server and attach database but it not connected and give error. operating system error 5:"5(access is denied.)"(microsoft sqlserver,error:5120) where is firewall port?